# python f-string and regular expression to generate customized path of a file in a directory

Tags: python, regex, os.path

**Given**:

Files in a working directory:

```
WKDIR = "/scratch/project_2004072/Nationalbiblioteket/dataframes"
$ ls -l
nikeX_docworks_lib_helsinki_fi_access_log_07_02_2021_lemmaMethod_stanza_27450_vocabs.json
nikeX_docworks_lib_helsinki_fi_access_log_07_02_2021_lemmaMethod_stanza_tfidf_matrix_RF_large.gz
nikeX_docworks_lib_helsinki_fi_access_log_07_02_2021_lemmaMethod_stanza_tfidf_vectorizer_large.gz
nikeX_docworks_lib_helsinki_fi_access_log_07_02_2021_lemmaMethod_stanza_user_tokens_df_27452_BoWs.gz
nikeY_docworks_lib_helsinki_fi_access_log_07_02_2021_lemmaMethod_stanza_26042_vocabs.json
nikeY_docworks_lib_helsinki_fi_access_log_07_02_2021_lemmaMethod_stanza_tfidf_matrix_RF_large.gz
nikeY_docworks_lib_helsinki_fi_access_log_07_02_2021_lemmaMethod_stanza_tfidf_vectorizer_large.gz
nikeY_docworks_lib_helsinki_fi_access_log_07_02_2021_lemmaMethod_stanza_user_tokens_df_26050_BoWs.gz
```

**Goal**:

I'd like to create a customized path using regular expression `fr` to only read files with endings of `user_tokens_df_XXXX_BoWs.gz` and load them via some helper function later in my code.
Right now, I have a python script with f-string and regex which does not work:

```
import re
import os
fprefix = f"nikeY_docworks_lib_helsinki_fi_access_log_07_02_2021_lemmaMethod_stanza_"
fpath = os.path.join(WKDIR, f'{fprefix}_user_token_sparse_df'fr'_user_tokens_df_(\d+)_BoWs.gz')
#fpath = os.path.join(WKDIR, f'{fprefix}_user_token_sparse_df'fr'(_user_tokens_df_(\d+)_BoWs.gz)') # did not work either!
print(fpath) # >>>> it's wrong! <<<<
try:
   # load via helper function
   df = load_pickle(fpath)
except:
   # do something else
```

Is there any better approach to fix this? Do I have a wrong understanding that using `re.search()` is not helping since this `fpath` is fed into another function in `try except` block in my code.

Cheers,

Comment: Did you test with `glob`?

Comment: `os.path.join()` does not do any kind of pattern filename matching.  It is the wrong function to use for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the description of the filename pattern given in the question, how about:

```
from glob import glob
    
PATTERN = "/scratch/project_2004072/Nationalbiblioteket/dataframes/*user_tokens_df_*_BoWs.gz"
    
for file in glob(PATTERN):
    ...
```

Comment: is there anyway to provide `"/scratch/project_2004072/Nationalbiblioteket/dataframes/"` as f-string directory added to my full `pattern`, as you named it here? because it is dynamic and changes from script to script

Comment: @FaridAlijani Yes - PATTERN could be an f-string. For example *PATTERN = f'{DIR}/\*user_tokens_df_\*_BoWs.gz'* then you just need to assign an appropriate value to DIR

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot! I use this: `PATTERN = DIR + "/" + "*user_tokens_df_*_BoWs.gz"`